# What compositors can I use in Unity-2D?

Tags: compiz, unity-2d, mutter, xcompmgr, xfwm4

I would like to install a compositor in unity 2D.

And I've noticed a number of other compositors: **compiz**, **mutter**, **xcompmgr**, **xfwm4**, etc.

I'm interested in using a lightweight compositor but I need to understand the differences between them.

Can someone give me guidance?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the use of the metacity compositor.  It's lightweight, effective, and generally used with Unity-2D.

To enable the metacity compositor, go to your terminal and paste:

`gconftool-2 -s '/apps/metacity/general/compositing_manager' --type bool true`

To disable:

`gconftool-2 -s '/apps/metacity/general/compositing_manager' --type bool false`

You may have to log out and log back in to see a difference.  Hope this helps!

---

To make the above process easier, the latest Ubuntu Tweak (0.7.1) can now enable and tweak metacity compositor settings.

See this article for more information.  http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/ubuntu-tweak-071-available-for-download.html